# Preventing Layout-land from returning to last fragment when screen orientation changes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have different layouts for landscape and for portrait. Starting from a home fragment, I then initiate a new fragment but when I change orientation on the new fragment, the view goes back to the home fragment layout. I tried putting  `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` on the manifest but the layout seemed to not work anymore. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Use `SharedPreferences` to store something to indicate which is your current Fragment. That way, when the orientation changes the FragmentManager can be set to use whatever is the current Fragment based on the `SharedPreferences` data.

Comment: So how do I achieve that? Do I have to use `onConfigurationChanged` with `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: Please post your code and perhaps some screenshots.